# Any way to convert road directions to paths in GEP?

Tags: google-earth

I have been trying to map out directions in GEP between 21 different places that I have imported into GEP as placemarks. I want to be able to create paths and tours between each one of them but its taking me hours to do it all by hand, is there an automatic way to create a path that follows the road directions in GEP?

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating a Map in MyMaps and exporting it to a KML file will create a path following road directions.